# Oracle.DataAccess connection 32bit in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle

How to make connection to oracle while compiling as 32bit in VB.NET?

I already successful connect oracle and build application using 64bit, with Oracle.DataAccess.
But, when I change build to 32bit, I got error "*TNS no listener*".

What I already did :

- I install NuGet Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
- Change compile platform to 32bit
- Download ODAC112040Xcopy_32bit and copy OraOps11w.dll to oracle_home/bin
- Add reference Oracle.DataAccess.dll from ODAC112040Xcopy_32bit

But error still happens.
Any advice?

Comment: In order to install both 32 bit and 64 bit Oracle Client (and thus also 32 bit and 64 bit Oracle.DataAccess), follow this instruction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Comment: `Oracle.DataAccess` is different to `Oracle.**Managed**DataAccess`. Oracle.ManagedDataAccess does not require any further Oracle Client installation, resp. any other dll. Oracle.ManagedDataAccess work in both, 32 bit and 64 bit application.

Comment: You need to decide, are you going to use `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` or `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`.

Comment: The point is I want to connect oracle with 32bit environment. I already try to use Oracle.DataAccess, but fail.